The smooth function with compact support on $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}.$
I have a smooth function defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ with compact support on $\Omega = [-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}.$ How can I use this condition?
I think if $u(x,y)$ is the smooth function with compact support on $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$ then there exist $N > 0$ such that $u(x,y)=0$ if $|y|>N$ or $u(x,y)=0$ if $|x| >1.$
Am I correct? Or we only have $u(x,y)=0$ if $|x| >1?$

There is no $x$ in $[-1, 1]$ with $|x| > 1$.

So you mean $u(x,y)=g(y)$ when $|x|>1,$ right?. How can we say about $y?$ Or how can we use component $\mathbb{R}$ of the domain?

I do not mean that, no. $u$ is defined on $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$, so you can only talk about $u(x, y)$ when $(x, y) \in [-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$.

I mean the function with compact support on $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$. But the function defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}.$

Your question should say that, then. Currently it reads as "smooth function defined on $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$ with compact support." Either way, do you know (a) what the support is and (b) when a subset of $[-1, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$ is compact?

@Delansi: I don't think your first statement is correct: look into bump functions. (If you define $u(x, y) = b(y)$ where $b(x)$ is a bump function on $\Bbb{R}$ you get a compactly supported smooth function that does not vanish on the boundary of the strip.)

@RobArthan you're correct of course, but would it vanish on the boundary if we had compact support in $(-1,1)\times \mathbb{R}$?

@Delansi: if the support were a subset of $(-1, 1) \times \Bbb{R}$ (compact or not), then the function would vanish on the boundary (because it vanishes outside the support).

OP is correct, although it may be helpful to think of how you can prove your propositions with as simple methods as possible given the definition.
